# Which part of boost library enables cout to print wstring and how?

Tags: c++, boost, cout, wstring

I just recently started to use boost library and found that after including a certain boost header (probably filesystem.h), the cout function can perfectly print out string and wstring in the same program. What's more, when printing wstring, the content is enclosed in quotation marks.

I'm very satisfied with the current behavior and want to fully understand the mechanism behind it to avoid any possible mispractice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::filesystem::path` has an implicit conversion constructor from `string_type`, which is defined as `std::basic_string<value_type>`. And `value_type` is defined variably depending upon environment. Notably, `wchar_t` on Windows. Which means on Windows, `string_type` is `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`, a.k.a. `std::wstring`.

So your `wstring` is being implicitly converted to a `boost::filesystem::path`, which is overloaded for printing through `operator<<`.